# Are Containable Parts and Widgets exclusive of each other?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm struggling with a decision to choose between creating a custom type as a Content Type with the Containable Part, or to create them as a Widget. I know that an existing Content Part can be used to create a new Widget, but this leaves me with having to create each instance from within the Widget Management section of the dashboard (I think). I'm not able to select a content item that already exists and have it act as a widget.

What I would really like is to have the ability to select a single, existing, Content Item and display it as a Widget. The widget could then expose a link that would take the user to the page-level display of that item. This would also allow me to have a list of these content types on a page where I also had html elements (html widgets) sprinkled in and amoungst them.

Alternatively, I could create my Content Type and attach the Containable Part. This would allow me to create the ad-hoc list (not a Projection) of content items I want. I would, however, have to create another Content Type to hold the HTML want to have appearing between the primary types.

Are my assumptions correct?:  Must one create a new instance of a widget when they add it to a zone? Or can they select one from a list of existing content types?
Are Containable Parts and Widgets exclusive of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a widget type with a content item picker field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Bertrand for the suggestion to create a widget type with a content item picker field. Here is my implementation:

```
public UpdateFrom1() {
    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("BioPickerWidget", cfg => cfg
        .WithPart("BioPickerWidget")
        .WithPart("WidgetPart")
        .WithPart("CommonPart")
        .WithSetting("Stereotype", "Widget"));

    ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("BioPickerWidget", cfg => cfg
        .WithField("BioPicker", fb => fb
            .OfType("ContentPickerField")
                .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.Hint", "Add Bio Content Items here.")
                .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.Required", "True")
                .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.Multiple", "True")
                .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.ShowContentTab", "True")
                .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.ShowSearchTab", "True")
                .WithSetting("ContentPickerFieldSettings.DisplayedContentTypes", "BioPart")
            .WithDisplayName("Bio Content Picker"))
                .WithSetting("ContentPartSettings.Attachable", "True")
            );


    return 2;
}
```

This allows me to add 1 or more of my *Bio* Content Types to a widget. Seems to be working nicely. All I have to do now is figure out the view customization.